# Compare two dates in a snapshot Table -TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a snapshot table which has a daily level information for a particular product and its price.
all I want to achieve is compare the state of this product from its current state to its previous state 2 months back.

Here is the ddl

```
CREATE TABLE Prod_snapshot
    ('Base_Date' datetime, 'Product_code' varchar(4));

INSERT INTO Prod_snapshot
    ('Base_Date', 'Product_code')
VALUES
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD1'),
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD2'),
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD2'),
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD1'),
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD3'),
    ('2013-10-01 13:00:00', 'VD9'),
    ('2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'VD1'),
    ('2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'VD2'),
    ('2014-02-01 13:00:00', 'VD10');
```

Here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4088e/1).

Here is my desired Output

```
Base_date Product_Code Active_on_01_oct_2013 
01/02/2014 VD1 'Y'
01/02/2014 VD2 'Y'
01/02/2014 VD10 'N'
```

Comment: is there anything you tried that didn't work well!

Comment: `2014-02-01` - `2013-10-01` is not two months by almost any measure I can think of. (Unless you're working with a roman calendar?)

Answer (score 0):

The basics of the query would be something like:

```
DECLARE @DateOfInterest date
SET @DateOfInterest = '20140201'

SELECT p1.Base_Date,pr.Product_Code,
     CASE WHEN p2.Product_Code IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END as PreviouslyActive
FROM
    Prod_snapshot p1
       left join
    Prod_snapshot p2
       on
          p1.Product_Code = p2.Product_Code and
          p2.Base_Date = DATEADD(month,-4 /* narrative says 2 */,@DateOfInterest)
WHERE
    p1.Base_Date = @DateOfInterest
```